# Pointcut targeting a third party JAR class is not triggered

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

As a temporary fix of the bug https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/220, I would like modify the return value of `org.springframework.hateoas.core.AnnotationMappingDiscoverer.getMapping` methods so that I can resolve placeholders manually. Here is the aspect I tried:

```xml
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class AnnotationMappingDiscovererFix {

  @Around("execution(* org.springframework.hateoas.core.AnnotationMappingDiscoverer.getMapping(..))")
  public Object resolvePlaceholders(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    Object mapping = joinPoint.proceed();
    // resolve placeholders manually...
    return mapping;
  }

}
```

But this pointcut gets never triggered, any idea why?

Comment: I believe compiler tries to inject `aop` codes at compile time only (I have seen this by decompiling bytecode of class having few aop intercepted methods). Here you are trying to intercept methods from precompiled jars. If you try doing the same on source then it should work.

Comment: @AnandShah How should I proceed then?

Comment: try using source of lib having `AnnotationMappingDiscoverer` class instead of lib as a jar package itself.

Answer (score 0):

With proxy-based Spring AOP you can only target Spring beans/components. I am not a Spring user, so I do not know for sure, but I do not think that you can actually intercept Spring framework classes via its own AOP framework due to "hen vs. egg" bootstrapping problems.

But if you use full AspectJ via load-time weaving (LTW), you should be able to achieve what you want because the AspectJ weaving agent (*aspectjweaver.jar*) is loaded before the Spring classes and thus can modify them during classloading phase. The [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) explains how to use AspectJ in connection with Spring.