# Is it possible to use AOP on the Button click event in Vaadin?

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, aspectj, spring-aop

I’m working on a Vaadin application, and I want to use an @Around aspect to intercept the method call when a Vaadin button is clicked. Specifically, I’d like to log information about the button click event. How can I achieve this using Spring AOP and the @Around advice? Or is this even possible?

My current demo project looks like this:

AspectDemoApplication.java:

```java
package com.example.aspectdemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AspectDemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AspectDemoApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

ClickInformation.java:

```java
package com.example.aspectdemo.config;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ClickInformation {

  @Around("execution(* com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener+.onComponentEvent(..))")
  public Object logClickInformation(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{
    String method = pjp.getSignature().getName();
    String targetClass = pjp.getTarget().getClass().getName();
    String params = Arrays.toString(pjp.getArgs());
    String msg = """
                      target: %s
                      method: %s
                      parameters: %s
                    """.formatted(targetClass, method, params);
    log.info(msg);
    return pjp.proceed();
  }
}
```

MainView.java:

```java
package com.example.aspectdemo.ui;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

@Route("")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {


  public MainView() {
    initUI();
  }

  public void initUI () {
    btnTest1 = new Button("Test1");
    btnTest2 = new Button("Test2");

    btnTest1.addClickListener(new ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent<Button>>() {

      @Override
      public void onComponentEvent(ClickEvent<Button> buttonClickEvent) {
        System.out.println("Button Test1 clicked");
      }
    });

    btnTest2.addClickListener(new ComponentEventListener<ClickEvent<Button>>() {

      @Override
      public void onComponentEvent(ClickEvent<Button> buttonClickEvent) {
        System.out.println("Button Test2 clicked");
      }
    });

    this.add(btnTest1, btnTest2);
  }


  public Button btnTest1;
  public Button btnTest2;

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to log information of the button click method call of every button click in the view using Aspect. I hope this makes it more clear.Am I missing something or is it just not possible? Thanks for your help in advance!

Best regards.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: Here in particular, please understand that there are so many ways in which you can misconfigure your aspect and the target code to be woven by it, that it would be pure speculation to try and help you. Things like class and package names, Spring configuration, annotations etc. are important, i.e. we need full(!) aspects, target classes and configs. I think I have a pretty good idea what might be wrong in your case, but I hate to speculate.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with an project example. Hope this makes it more clear!

Comment: This kind of question literally has been asked dozens or hundreds of times here already. My advice to you is, like to your predecessors, to actually study some examples or documentation before using a new tool.

Comment: @kriegaex when this question has already been asked hundreds of times, could you list some of these questions?

Comment: Sure. Here are just a few I answered myself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64289370/1082681, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50093552/108268, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57456924/1082681, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38158365/1082681, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31629976/1082681. There are more where these came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring AOP works, as implied by the name and documented, only for Spring-managed beans or components (`@Component`, `@Bean`, `@Service` etc.). Your anonymous listener classes are not spring-managed. Hence, Spring AOP cannot intercept them. Either make sure your target classes are in fact Spring-managed or switch to [native AspectJ](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/using-aspectj.html).